# Authenticating service accounts using signed jwt via keycloak

Tags: authentication, jwt, keycloak

I'm looking at deploying Keycloak as our authentication system, as it offers a bunch of great benefits (like easy integration with customer IdP's and full support for the oauth2 universe of protocols). The main question I have now is about how to authenticate service accounts without sending usernames and passwords over the network.

What I'd like to do is have an authentication flow for service accounts that support a signed JWT mechanism where the user would create a signed JWT then send that to the keycloak server which could verify it by using the registered public key for that service. Keycloak would respond with the Bearer token (JWT), and a refresh token.

It appears that keycloak can do this, based on this mailing list thread: https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-dev/2015-August/005112.html and this merged PR: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/1545, but their interface has changed since 2015 and it's not clear how to get this working.

Has anyone been able to get keycloak to authenticate service accounts (and also users) using signed tokens? Any tips on how I would do it?

Thanks,
-S

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured this out.

From their documentation on [Confidential Client Credentials](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_client-credentials), we have these instructions:

> If you’ve set the client’s access type to confidential in the client’s Settings tab, a new Credentials tab will show up. As part of dealing with this type of client you have to configure the client’s credentials.

What they leave out is that the "Credentials" tab doesn't show up until you've clicked "Save" with "Access Type" set to "confidential". I've created a PR to address the hole in the docs [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/pull/859).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it using Quarkus 3, authenticating to Keycloak 21 by signed JWT.

Assuming keycloak is hosted on `http://localhost:8080` and Quarkus (as client) is hosted on `http://localhost:9090`, and the realm name is `myrealm`.

On Keycloak side:

1. Go to admin console, and create new client:

- Client type: `OpenID Connect`.
- Client ID: `keycloak-client`
- Name: `Keyclaok Client`
- Enable `Client authentication` and `Service account roles`
- Click `Save`.

[image]
[image]

2. On `Credentials` tab:

- Client Authenticator: `Signed Jwt`
- Signature algorithm: `RS256`

3. On `Keys` tab:

- Set `Use JWKS URL` to `On`.
- JWKS URL: `http://localhost:9090/oauth/k_jwks`

Note: I set `JWKS URL` to `http://host.docker.internal:9090/oauth/k_jwks` as Keycloak is hosted on docker container (using Quarkus Devservices) and Quarkus is hosted on the host machine.

On Quarkus side:

1. Create REST endpoint that exposes JWKS:

```
import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public record JsonWebKeySet(
    @JsonProperty("keys") List<JsonWebKey> keys
){
    public record JsonWebKey(
        @JsonProperty("kid") String keyId,
        @JsonProperty("kty") String keyType,
        @JsonProperty("alg") String algorithm,
        @JsonProperty("use") String publicKeyUse,
        @JsonProperty("n") String modulus,
        @JsonProperty("e") String publicExponent,
        // Note that the following parts seem to be optional and it works fine without them
        @JsonProperty("x5c") List<String> x509CertificateChain,
        @JsonProperty("x5t") String sha1x509Thumbprint,
        @JsonProperty("x5t#S256") String sha256x509Thumbprint
    ){}
}
```

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509v1CertificateBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;
import org.keycloak.crypto.KeyType;
import org.keycloak.crypto.KeyUse;
import org.keycloak.jose.jwk.JWKUtil;
import io.smallrye.jwt.algorithm.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.smallrye.jwt.build.Jwt;
import io.smallrye.jwt.util.KeyUtils;
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@ApplicationScoped
public class OAuthUtils {
    
    private SignatureAlgorithm keycloakAdminClientJwtSignatureAlgorithm;
    private PrivateKey keycloakAdminClientPrivateKey;
    private RSAPublicKey keycloakAdminClientPublicKey;
    
    @ConfigProperty(name = "keycloak.admin-client.jwt.signature-algorithm")
    String keycloakAdminClientJwtSignatureAlgorithmAsText;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "keycloak.admin-client.jwt.key-id")
    String keycloakAdminClientKeyId;
    
    @ConfigProperty(name = "keycloak.admin-client.jwt.private-key")
    String keycloakAdminClientPrivateKeyPemEncoded;
    
    @ConfigProperty(name = "keycloak.admin-client.jwt.public-key")
    String keycloakAdminClientPublicKeyPemEncoded;
    
    @ConfigProperty(name = "keycloak.admin-client.jwt.certificate")
    String keycloakAdminClientCertificatePemEncoded;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void initKeys() {
        try {
            keycloakAdminClientJwtSignatureAlgorithm =
                                            SignatureAlgorithm.fromAlgorithm(keycloakAdminClientJwtSignatureAlgorithmAsText);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to instantiate JWT signature algorithm (%s)!"
                                                                .formatted(keycloakAdminClientJwtSignatureAlgorithmAsText), e);
        }
        
        try {
            keycloakAdminClientPrivateKey = KeyUtils.decodePrivateKey(keycloakAdminClientPrivateKeyPemEncoded,
                                                                      keycloakAdminClientJwtSignatureAlgorithm);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to instantiate Keycloak admin client private key!", e);
        }
        
        try {
            keycloakAdminClientPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) KeyUtils.decodePublicKey(keycloakAdminClientPublicKeyPemEncoded,
                                                                                   keycloakAdminClientJwtSignatureAlgorithm);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to instantiate Keycloak admin client public key!", e);
        }
    }
    
    public String createKeycloakAdminClientJwt() {
        return Jwt.claims()
                  .issuedAt(Instant.now())
                  .expiresAt(Instant.now().plusSeconds(300))
                  .claim("jti", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                  .audience("http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm")
                  .issuer("keycloak-client")
                  .subject("keycloak-client")
                  .jws()
                  .keyId(keycloakAdminClientKeyId)
                  .algorithm(keycloakAdminClientJwtSignatureAlgorithm)
                  .sign(keycloakAdminClientPrivateKey);
    }
    
    public JsonWebKeySet getKeycloakAdminJwks() {
        try {
            String modulus = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(
                                            JWKUtil.toIntegerBytes(keycloakAdminClientPublicKey.getModulus()));
            String publicExponent = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(
                                            JWKUtil.toIntegerBytes(keycloakAdminClientPublicKey.getPublicExponent()));
            String sha1x509Thumbprint = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(
                                            MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest());
            String sha256x509Thumbprint = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(
                                            MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest());
            var jsonWebKey = new JsonWebKey(keycloakAdminClientKeyId, KeyType.RSA, keycloakAdminClientJwtSignatureAlgorithmAsText,
                                            KeyUse.SIG.getSpecName(), modulus, publicExponent,
                                            List.of(keycloakAdminClientCertificatePemEncoded),
                                            sha1x509Thumbprint, sha256x509Thumbprint);
            return new JsonWebKeySet(List.of(jsonWebKey));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to construct JWKS!", e);
        }
    }
    
    // Note that the certificate part seems to be optional, and it works fine without it if you do not want to include Bouncy Castle dependencies
    public record CertificateWithKeys(String keyId, String privateKeyEncoded,
                                      String publicKeyEncoded, String certificateEncoded){}
    public static CertificateWithKeys generateV1SelfSignedCertificateWithPrivateKey(int keySize, String subject)
                                            throws CertificateException, OperatorCreationException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        var keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(keySize);
        var keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        
        var serialNumber = BigInteger.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        var subjectDN = new X500Name("CN=" + subject);
        Date validityStartDate = Date.from(LocalDate.now().minusDays(1)
                                                    .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
        Date validityEndDate = Date.from(LocalDate.now().plusYears(10)
                                                  .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
        var subPubKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded());
        
        var contentSigner = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WithRSAEncryption")
                                                            .setProvider("BC").build(keyPair.getPrivate());
        var x509CertificateHolder = new X509v1CertificateBuilder(subjectDN, serialNumber, validityStartDate, validityEndDate,
                                                                 subjectDN, subPubKeyInfo).build(contentSigner);
        var certificate = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().getCertificate(x509CertificateHolder);
        
        String keyId = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(
                        MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded()));
        String privateKeyEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
        String publicKeyEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded());
        String certificateEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(certificate.getEncoded());
        
        return new CertificateWithKeys(keyId, privateKeyEncoded, publicKeyEncoded, certificateEncoded);
    }
}
```

```
import org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.ResponseStatus;
import jakarta.annotation.security.PermitAll;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/oauth")
public class OAuthEndpoints {
    
    @Inject OAuthUtils oAuthUtils;
    
    @ResponseStatus(200) // OK
    @GET
    @PermitAll
    @Path("/oauth/k_jwks")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JsonWebKeySet getJsonWebKeySet() {
        return oAuthUtils.getKeycloakAdminJwks();
    }
}
```

2. You can acquire the access token and construct `Keycloak` object as follows:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak;
import org.keycloak.admin.client.KeycloakBuilder;
import io.quarkus.oidc.client.OidcClient;
import io.quarkus.oidc.client.OidcClientConfig;
import io.quarkus.oidc.client.OidcClientConfig.Grant.Type;
import io.quarkus.oidc.client.OidcClients;
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;

@ApplicationScoped
public class KeycloakAdminClient {
    
    private OidcClient oidcClient;
    
    @SuppressWarnings("CdiInjectionPointsInspection")
    @Inject OidcClients oidcClients;
    
    @Inject OAuthUtils oAuthUtils;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        var oidcClientConfig = new OidcClientConfig();
        oidcClientConfig.setId("keycloak-client");
        oidcClientConfig.setClientId("keycloak-client");
        oidcClientConfig.setAuthServerUrl("http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm");
        oidcClientConfig.getGrant().setType(Type.CLIENT);
        oidcClientConfig.setScopes(List.of("openid"));
        oidcClient = oidcClients.newClient(oidcClientConfig).await().indefinitely();
    }
}
    
    public Keycloak createNewKeycloakClient() {
        String jwt = oAuthUtils.createKeycloakAdminClientJwt();
        var additionalGrantParameters = Map.of("client_assertion", jwt, "client_assertion_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer"); 
        String accessToken = oidcClient.getTokens(additionalGrantParameters).await().atMost(Duration.ofSeconds(60)).getAccessToken();
        return KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                              .serverUrl("http://localhost:8080")
                              .realm("myrealm")
                              .clientId("keycloak-client")
                              .authorization(accessToken)
                              .build();
    }
```

Note: the following dependencies are used:

```
io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson
io.quarkus:quarkus-oidc
io.quarkus:quarkus-keycloak-admin-client-reactive
io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-jwt-build
io.quarkus:quarkus-oidc-client
org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk18on
```